# Example of a nowhere differentiable contraction mapping

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

The Weierstrass function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

is a pathological example of a continuous nowhere differentiable function.. Since a conttaction mapping is necessarily Lipschitz continuous (which is a stronger form of continuity), I was wondering if there exists a (pathological) example of a contraction mapping that is nowhere differentiable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher's_theorem) a Lipschitz function $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is differentiable almost everywhere. A proof of this result can be found, for example, in Emmanuele DiBenedetto's *Real Analysis*, Theorem 21.1.